# Change Vue app background image for each route

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, background-image

I need to add a background image to some of the routes of my application, and leave it blank to others

This is my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="h-100">
      <div class="bg" >
        <NavBar/>
        <router-view></router-view>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>
```

And to try to add the image in /, is use the  component of my Home.vue like this:

```
<style >
.bg {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../assets/equipo.jpg') !important;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

This makes that image background of all the application, so then I try to remove it in one of the components in which I don't want the background image like this:

```
<style >
 .bg {
   background-image: none;
 }
</style>
```

Which removes the image from all the application routes. I also tried with the scoped style for the second component and doesn't work.

I think the question would be:
How can I access a parent's element from the scoped style of a child?

Comment: You could probably use this.$parent, but why do not just created computed prop and based on page it will add class to the page

Comment: You could create a computed style value like in this link https://www.telerik.com/blogs/passing-variables-to-css-on-a-vue-component That may be the best choice.

Comment: how would the parent get access to the computed value?

Answer (score 0):

On your component(s) you can use "scoped" style:

```
<style scoped>
// your CSS here - this CSS will only affect the component and not propagate to other components.
</style>
```

Comment: This wont work since the element i want to style is wrapping the scoped component from his parent.